# Loading and parsing a JSON file with multiple JSON objects

Tags: python, json, file, jsonlines

I am trying to load and parse a JSON file in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29). But I'm stuck trying to load the file:

```
import json
json_data = open('file')
data = json.load(json_data)
```

Yields:

```
ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 225116 column 1 (char 232 - 160128774)
```

I looked at *[18.2. `json` — JSON encoder and decoder](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html)* in the Python documentation, but it's pretty discouraging to read through this horrible-looking documentation.

First few lines (anonymized with randomized entries):

```json
{"votes": {"funny": 2, "useful": 5, "cool": 1}, "user_id": "harveydennis", "name": "Jasmine Graham", "url": "http://example.org/user_details?userid=harveydennis", "average_stars": 3.5, "review_count": 12, "type": "user"}
{"votes": {"funny": 1, "useful": 2, "cool": 4}, "user_id": "njohnson", "name": "Zachary Ballard", "url": "https://www.example.com/user_details?userid=njohnson", "average_stars": 3.5, "review_count": 12, "type": "user"}
{"votes": {"funny": 1, "useful": 0, "cool": 4}, "user_id": "david06", "name": "Jonathan George", "url": "https://example.com/user_details?userid=david06", "average_stars": 3.5, "review_count": 12, "type": "user"}
{"votes": {"funny": 6, "useful": 5, "cool": 0}, "user_id": "santiagoerika", "name": "Amanda Taylor", "url": "https://www.example.com/user_details?userid=santiagoerika", "average_stars": 3.5, "review_count": 12, "type": "user"}
{"votes": {"funny": 1, "useful": 8, "cool": 2}, "user_id": "rodriguezdennis", "name": "Jennifer Roach", "url": "http://www.example.com/user_details?userid=rodriguezdennis", "average_stars": 3.5, "review_count": 12, "type": "user"}
```

Answer (score 305, accepted):

You have a [JSON Lines format text file](http://jsonlines.org/). You need to parse your file line by line:

```
import json

data = []
with open('file') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(json.loads(line))
```

Each *line* contains valid JSON, but as a whole, it is not a valid JSON value as there is no top-level list or object definition.

Note that because the file contains JSON per line, you are saved the headaches of trying to parse it all in one go or to figure out a streaming JSON parser. You can now opt to process each line separately before moving on to the next, saving memory in the process. You probably don't want to append each result to one list and *then* process everything if your file is really big.

If you have a file containing individual JSON objects with delimiters in-between, use [How do I use the 'json' module to read in one JSON object at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708192/how-do-i-use-the-json-module-to-read-in-one-json-object-at-a-time/21709058#21709058) to parse out individual objects using a buffered method.

Comment: +1 Maybe it is worth noting, that if you do not need all objects at once, processing them one-by-one may be more efficient approach. This way you will not need to store whole data in the memory, but a single piece of it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, my assumption about the file not being ill-formatted was wrong.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Knowing the structure of the JSONs is there anyway I could parse the data calling each field by their names?

Comment: @Pi_: you'll have a dictionary, so just access the fields as keys: `data = json.loads(line); print data[u'votes']`

Comment: @MartijnPieters that gives me a KeyError

Comment: @Pi_: print the result of json.loads() then or use the debugger to inspect.

Comment: @MartijnPieters All it seems to be doing is copying the lines from the file and appending them to data[] while adding 'u' in front of each field of each json-object.

Comment: @Pi_: no; don't confuse the JSON format with the python dict representation. You are seeing python dictionaries with strings now.

Comment: How to parse JSON though when the value part has multiple lines?

Comment: @user2441441: see the [linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708192/how-do-i-use-the-json-module-to-read-in-one-json-object-at-a-time/21709058#21709058) from the post here.

Comment: I was writing a json object per line anyways, thanks for pointing to the "official specification" (I wanted to know a good suffix for the filetype)

Answer (score 28):

In case you are using `pandas` and you will be interested in loading the `json` file as a dataframe, you can use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('file.json', lines=True)
```

And to convert it into a json array, you can use:

```
df.to_json('new_file.json')
```

Comment: This answer is the most pythonic in my view.

Answer (score 20):

for those stumbling upon this question: the python `jsonlines` library (much younger than this question) elegantly handles files with one json document per line. see https://jsonlines.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 1):

Just like [Martijn Pieters' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12451465/3710501) but maybe a bit more pythonic,  and most of all, which enables streaming of data (see second part of the answer):

```
import json

with open(filepath, "r") as f:
    return list(map(json.loads, f))
```

The `map(function, iterable)` function returns an iterator that applies `function` to every item of `iterable`, yielding the results (cf [map() python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)).
And the `list` transforms this iterator into... a list :)
But you can imagine to **directly use the iterator returned by map** instead: it iterates over each of your json lines. Note that in that case you need to do it in the `with open(filepath, "r") as f` context: that is the strength of this approach, **the json lines are not fully loaded in a list, they are streamed**: the map function read each line of the file when `next(iterator)` is called by the `for loop`. 
It would give:

```
import json

with open(file path, "r") as f:
    iterator_over_lines = map(json.loads, f)
    # just as you would do with a list but here the file is streamed
    for jsonline in iterator_over_lines:
         # do something for each line
    # the function mapped, json.loads is only call on each iteration
    # that's why the file must stay opened

    # You can try to call yourself the next function used by the for loop:
    next_jsonline = next(iterator_over_lines)
    nextnext_jsonline = next(iterator_over_lines)
```

And I have nothing to add to Martijn's answer for explanations about what is a jsonl (json line by line file) and why use it!

Answer (score 0):

That *is* ill-formatted. You have one JSON object per line, but they are not contained in a larger data structure (ie an array). You'll either need to reformat it so that it begins with `[` and ends with `]` with a comma at the end of each line, or parse it line by line as separate dictionaries.

Comment: With a 50MB file the OP is probably better off dealing with the data line by line anyway. :-)

Comment: Whether the file is ill-formatted depends on one's point of view.  If it was intended to be in the "JSON lines" format, it's valid.  See: http://jsonlines.org/

Comment: I love how browsers throw away 2500MB at a time, and people don't want to use 50MB to actually process something.

Answer (score 0):

Add-on to @arunppsg's answer, but with multiprocessing to deal with a large number of files in a directory.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json
import os
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

directory = 'your_directory'

def read_json(json_files):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for j in json_files:
        with open(os.path.join(directory, j)) as f:
            df = df.append(pd.read_json(f, lines=True)) # if there's multiple lines in the json file, flag lines to true, false otherwise.
    return df

def parallelize_json(json_files, func):
    json_files_split = np.array_split(json_files, 10)
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, json_files_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df

# start the timer
start = time.time()

# read all json files in parallel
df = parallelize_json(json_files, read_json)

# end the timer
end = time.time()

# print the time taken to read all json files
print(end - start)
```