# Using json with list of lists. How to append lists in loop in file and later load it as list of lists

Tags: python, json

I use a loop to every time add a new list called `lst` to my txt file with this

```
with open('database.txt','a+') as myfile:
    json.dump(lst,myfile)
```

but I want JSON to every time put a new list in a new row. How to do that? So I could later extract line by line and return it to list in program.

Or, can I insert ',' somehow between lists, so when I load the file and read it, get usable list of lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a newline after every JSON dump:

```
with open('database.txt','a+') as myfile:
    json.dump(lst, myfile)
    myfile.write('\n')
```

Then, provided you [read the file line-by-line later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451431/loading-parsing-json-file-in-python/12451465#12451465), you can load the JSON into Python objects again.