# Export dicts to a json file

Tags: python, json, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list of dicts `j` and I would like to export some of the dicts as a json file called `myFile.json` :

```
for item in j:
    if item['start'] = "True":
        #If myFile.json exists then append item to myFile.json
        #Otherwise create myFile.json that starts with "[" and append item to it
#Append "]" to the myFile.json
```

I can do it using `try` , but I would like to know if there is a more pythonic way to make it .

My code doesn't even worth to put it.

```
try:
    with io.open(myFile.json, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(unicode(json.dumps(item, ensure_ascii=False)))
        f.write(u",")
except IOError:
    with io.open(myFile.json, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(u"[")
    with io.open(myFile.json, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(unicode(json.dumps(item, ensure_ascii=False)))
        f.write(u",")

        # ..etc
```

**Edit**
The output file should be a json array:

```
[ {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"key1":"value3","key2":"value4"}]
```

Comment: I don't understand how you can have valid JSON in your file if you can append data to it. Also, you need to fix your indentation. Presumably, the exception-catch should be at the same level as the try.

Comment: This code doesn't run, right? `if item['start'] = "True":` You want something more like: `if item['start']` where `item['start']` is a boolean, not a string.

Comment: @hughdbrown I don't have a valid json file but I would like to create it . The code run but without "True" in it, what I wrote is just an example..

Comment: I'm confused as to why you can't combine them all into a list before writing (should only be doing file i/o at the end of processing).  I'm also confused as to why you couldn't open the file, read in the data, do a json.loads() and then append things to the list before rewriting it out.  I tried doing what you're trying to do and it's a freaking headache, and usually you'll miss something on the formatting and be stuck with almost well formatted JSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach has a severe flaw: If you are writing `[` first, you also need to add `,` commas after each JSON value you write, you have to append the closing `]`, and then you have to *remove* the last `]` every time you append to the file, or on reading manually add the `]` closing bracket before decoding.

You'd be better of *not* trying to build a big JSON list, and instead use newlines as delimiters. That way you can freely append, and by [reading your file line-by-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451431/loading-parsing-json-file-in-python/12451465#12451465) you can easily load the data again.

This has the added advantage of *vastly* simplifying your code:

```
with io.open(myFile.json, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(unicode(json.dumps(item, ensure_ascii=False)))
    f.write(u'\n')
```

This removes the need to test for the file existing first. Reading is as simple as:

```
with open(myFile.json) as f:
    for line in f:
        data = json.loads(line)
```

Comment: Thank you @Martijn the second code is good for me, but why it doesn't create file if it doesn't exist, and doesn't work if I added this `open(myfile, 'w').close()` before ?

Comment: @4m1nh4j1: opening a file in append mode creates the file for you if it doesn't exist.