# Nulls, instead of Nones, in JSON Data with Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I'm working with the following data:

```
[{"title": null, "metric1": 361429, "metric2": 36,},{"title": null, "metric1": 253798, "metric2": 48}]
```

When I attempt to assign this data to a variable in Python (with the aim of parsing it out), I receive the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'null' is not defined
```

From my research, it appears that the `None` is Python's `null`.  What I'm wondering is, is it possible to change the `null`'s in my data to `None`'s using Python?

I've tried creating a string out of the data, assigning it to `data`, and replacing the `null`'s that way:

```
data = data.replace('null','None')
```

but that results in a string of the data itself:

```
data = '[{"title": None, "metric1": 361429, "metric2": 36,},{"title": None, "metric1": 253798, "metric2": 48}]'
```

and I can't figure out how to turn it from a string back into JSON.

EDIT: I am copying and pasting this data into the Python interpreter from a separate source.

Comment: The correct way to convert a JSON string into a python object is [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) -- no string munging necessary.

Comment: That's not a json string. The comma at the end of `"metric2": 36,` shouldn't be there.

Comment: It seems like you are pasting this into the python interpreter (which means its python syntax, not JSON). Is that the case, and if so, why not mention it?

Comment: @tdelaney you are correct!  I am copying and pasting into the interpreter.  Apologies for not mentioning; it wasn't on purpose, just a detail that slipped my mind.  Good call.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Much simpler!

Just assign `None` to `null` before assigning that list to a variable:

```
null = None
var = [{"title": null, "metric1": 361429, "metric2": 36,},{"title": null, "metric1": 253798, "metric2": 48}]
```

Then you won't need to do the rather unnecessary conversion to a string (and back to a Python object with `json.loads`) only to replace `null` by `None`.

But that is only really necessary if you're copy-pasting that code from some source. Otherwise, the canonical answer is to use `json.loads` (or `json.load`).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Oliver W.!  Very clever.  This is exactly what I needed.  Very good insight with the copy/paste even though I forgot to mention it.

Comment: I thought it's so tricky. How about another way to convert it to `None`?

Comment: How simple. I would never name a name as null and could't think of that solution!

Answer (score 14):

As is mentioned above, you don't need to replace `"null"` for `"None"`

Just

```
import json
parsed_data = json.loads(data)
```

Comment: Thanks @levi!  This makes perfect sense.  Will do for future json and python endeavors.  +1 for your answer.