# how to convert string to array with values in python

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

We do have this string:

```json
{"transaction_invoiceno":"11111","fallback":false,"emvTags":"null"}
```

How to convert this string to list or array so we can get values and print them, for example:

```
transaction_invoiceno = 11111
fallback = false
emvTags = null
```

Comment: You are using double quote inside a string which is enclosed using double quote, which is wrong. Is it a file or a string?

Comment: You can try using `d = json.loads(your_string)`. After this you can access your variable using `d['transaction_invoiceno']`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt [json](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp) library like this although you need to replace your double quotes with single ones or you'll get an error.

If you want to iterate through the key, value pairs of the dictionary you can simply use the [.items()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) method.

```
import json

my_json = '{"transaction_invoiceno":"11111","fallback":false,"emvTags":"null"}'
my_dict = json.loads(my_json)

for k,v in my_dict.items():
    print(k, v)

transaction_invoiceno 11111
fallback False
emvTags null
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like the following snippet should do the trick:

```
s = '{"transaction_invoiceno":"11111","fallback":false,"emvTags":"null"}'
s = s.replace('false', 'False')
exec('d = '+ s)

transaction_invoiceno = int(d["transaction_invoiceno"])
fallback = d["fallback"]
emvTags = d["emvTags"]
```

However, the `null` will be a string.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best method to resolve this issue is given by [User:Johnny John Boy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67125800/14867730). This is another way check out this code:

```
my_json = '{"transaction_invoiceno":"11111","fallback":false,"emvTags":"null"}'.replace('false', 'False')
my_dict = eval(my_json)

for k,v in my_dict.items():
    print(k, v)
```

For more detail you can check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28843950/14867730)

Comment: It's interesting, I started with this approach and thought it looked like he was doing API stuff so changed my approach :-) I prefer yours

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

data = json.loads('{"transaction_invoiceno":"11111","fallback":false,"emvTags":"null"}') 

#
# Get values by key name
#
transaction_invoiceno = data['transaction_invoiceno']
fallback              = data['fallback']
emvTags               = data['emvTags']

#
# Convert data types ("fallback" already set to bool by json.loads)
#
transaction_invoiceno = int(transaction_invoiceno)
emvTags = (None if data['emvTags'] == "null" else data['emvTags']) 

#
# Check types
#
print f"transaction_invoiceno: type: {type(transaction_invoiceno)}, value: {transaction_invoiceno}")
print(f"fallback: type: {type(fallback)}, value: {fallback}")
print(f"emvTags: type: {type(emvTags)}, value: {emvTags}")
```