# Loading a file as a JSON in python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, load

I'm quite new to python and im trying to get a JSON file to be created and then loaded and then organised. But I keep getting a weird error.

This is my code to write the file:

```
def save(): # save to file
    with open(class_name, 'a') as f:
        data = [name, score]
        json.dump(data, f)
```

This is my code to load the file:

```
with open(class_name, 'r') as f:
            data2 = json.load(f)
```

This is my code to organise the file:

```
with open(class_name, 'r') as f:
            data2 = json.load(f)
            Alpha = sorted(data, key=str.lower)
        print(Alpha)
```

And this is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    viewscores()
  File "C:\Users\Danny\Desktop\Task123.py", line 60, in viewscores
    data2 = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py", line 268, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py", line 318, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 346, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 13 - line 1 column 153 (char 12 - 152)
```

Comment: open the file in 'w' mode, not 'a'. also, Alpha should be equal to sorted(data2...), not sorted(data...)

Answer (score 0):

You are *appending* data to your file, creating multiple JSON documents in that file. The `json.load()` command on the other hand can only load *one* JSON document from a file, and is now complaining you have more data after the JSON document.

Either adjust your code to load those documents separately (insert newlines after each entry you append, and [load the JSON documents line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451431/loading-and-parsing-a-json-file-in-python), or replace *everything* in the file with a new JSON object.

Using newlines as separators, then loading all the entries separately would look like:

```
def save(): # save to file
    with open(class_name, 'a') as f:
        data = [name, score]
        json.dump(data, f)
        f.write('\n')
```

and loading would be:

```
with open(class_name, 'r') as f:
    scores = []
    for line in f:
        entry = json.loads(line)
        scores.append(entry)
```

after which you could sort those entries if you so wish.

Comment: Where would I load the JSON documents by line?

Comment: @DannyAtcheson: where you use `json.load(f)` now. If you wanted to have a whole list of entries to sort, you'd load each line, append it to a list object, then sort.

Comment: sorry for a noob atm, but how would i do that?

Comment: @DannyAtcheson: I already added sample code to the answer. :-)

Comment: doesn't matter now, 'tis all fixed