# Converting raw ASCII text with UTF-8 encoded characters represented by backslash escapes

Tags: python, json, twitter, encoding, utf-8

I collect Persian tweets running the following python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import sys
import tweepy
import json
import os

consumer_key ="xxxx"
consumer_secret ="xxxx"
access_key = "xxxx"
access_secret = "xxxx"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

save_file = open("Out.json", 'a')

t1 = u""

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, api):
        self.api = api
        super(tweepy.StreamListener, self).__init__()

        # self.list_of_tweets = []

    def on_data(self, tweet):
        print tweet
        save_file.write(str(tweet))

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True # Don't kill the stream
        print "Stream restarted"

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True # Don't kill the stream
        print "Stream restarted"

def start_stream():
    while True:
        try:
            sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener(api))
            sapi.filter(track=[t1])
        except: 
            continue

start_stream()
```

It returns tweets text in raw ASCII text with UTF-8 encoded characters represented by backslash escapes. I would like to change the code in a way that directly saves the retrieved tweets in "Out.json" in UTF-8 encoded format.

```
{
    "created_at": "Tue Feb 07 08:04:17 +0000 2017",
    "id": 828877025049972737,
    "id_str": "828877025049972737",
    "text": "\u0644\u0637\u0641\u0627 \u0628\u0647 \u062d\u06cc\u0648\u0627\u0646\u0627\u062a \u063a\u06cc\u0631\u062e\u0627\u0646\u06af\u06cc \u063a\u0630\u0627\u00a0\u0646\u062f\u0647\u06cc\u062f https:\/\/t.co\/gFi5XCVQww https:\/\/t.co\/pQWPqbvJVF",
    "display_text_range": [0, 58],
    "source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/publicize.wp.com\/\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eWordPress.com\u003c\/a\u003e",
    "truncated": false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    ...
    "lang": "fa",
    "timestamp_ms": "1486454657219"
}
```

Comment: That's *valid JSON data*. I'm not sure what you expected instead. What did you want to see saved? Note that UTF-8 is a *superset* of ASCII, so **all** characters in there are UTF-8. If you want to generate JSON without `\uhhhh` escapes (so save the raw character as UTF-8 bytes rather than a JSON escape sequence), then you'll have to decode, and re-encode. See [Saving utf-8 texts in json.dumps as UTF8, not as \u escape sequence](//stackoverflow.com/q/18337407)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `StreamListener.on_data()` method is passed the raw JSON data as received from Twitter. It is this data that contains valid JSON escape sequences.

If you wanted to save UTF-8 data directly, so with the `\uhhhh` escape sequences replaced by the actual Unicode codepoint, you'll have to *re-code* the tweet. Use [Saving utf-8 texts in json.dumps as UTF8, not as \u escape sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337407/saving-utf-8-texts-in-json-dumps-as-utf8-not-as-u-escape-sequence) to save the data afterwards.

Do note that writing multiple JSON objects to one file makes that file itself invalid JSON. You could produce [JSON Lines output](http://jsonlines.org/) by injecting newlines (the standard `json.dumps()` output does not produce newlines in the generated JSON document), then read those entries one by one with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451431/loading-and-parsing-a-json-file-in-python/12451465#12451465).

So the important sections of your code should look like:

```
import json

save_file = open("Out.json", 'a')

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    # ...

    def on_data(self, tweet):
        tweet = json.loads(tweet)
        json_doc = json.dumps(tweet, ensure_ascii=False)
        save_file.write(json_doc.encode('utf8') + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `str` call:

```
# ...

def on_data(self, tweet):
    print tweet
    save_file.write(tweet)

# ...
```

If it doesn't help, open your file using [codecs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) module:

```
save_file = codecs.open("Out.json", 'a', encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: Don't use `codecs.open()`; rather use `io.open()`; that's the Python 3 framework, which is *much* more robust than the `codecs` framework.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Removed 'str' but no success.

Comment: @farlay: that's because your data is **already JSON encoded**, already a string.