# JSON load error: extra data

Tags: python, json, load

**i am trying to load a json file through following code**

```
import json

with open('ass1//data//reviews_Digital_Music.json', encoding="utf8") as f:
    review = json.load(f,encoding="utf8")
```

**Return error**

```
C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 342, in decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
JSONDecodeError: Extra data
```

for more insight you can find part of my json file, the document has 10000 more such dictionary

```
{"reviewerID": "A2EFCYXHNK06IS","asin": "5555991584", "reviewerName": "Abigail Perkins \"Abby &#34;Reads Too Much&#34...", "helpful": [4, 5], "reviewText": "text", "overall": 5.0, "summary": "Enya Experiments And Succeeds", "unixReviewTime": 978480000, "reviewTime": "01 3, 2001"}
{"reviewerID": "A1WR23ER5HMAA9", "asin": "5555991584", "reviewerName": "AKB", "helpful": [1, 1], "reviewText": "text", "overall": 5.0, "summary": "How to improve upon perfection.", "unixReviewTime": 953424000, "reviewTime": "03 19, 2000"}
{"reviewerID": "A2IR4Q0GPAFJKW", "asin": "5555991584", "reviewerName": "Alexander", "helpful": [0, 0], "reviewText": "text", "overall": 4.0, "summary": "Good listening.", "unixReviewTime": 1393545600, "reviewTime": "02 28, 2014"}
```

how can i load it as dic?

Comment: ``part of my json file`` is not helpful for us to help you. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: should i upload the json file? it is 32GB

Comment: No, please provide a **minimal**, complete and verifiable example.

Comment: Isn't it should be `'r'` like:  `with open('ass1//data//reviews_Digital_Music.json', 'r') as f:`

Comment: It looks like your json file is a little wonky. What process did you go through to make it? How exactly is it structured? Check out this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058935/python-json-loads-shows-valueerror-extra-data

Comment: i already have seen this question, perhaps nested dictionary inside each other was the cause of error but in my case as you see it is just dictionary with a list inside. the document has 10000 more such dictionary. also i tried with "r", there is same issue

Comment: @beegee: It doesn't because `'r'` is the default mode for `open()`.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451431/loading-and-parsing-a-json-file-with-multiple-json-objects-in-python

Comment: @ArndtJonasson Thank you, it work