# ValueError: Expecting ',' delimiter, while trying to load string as json in python3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, file-io

I have around 5 million tweets in the following format:

```
{"created_at":"Mon May 21 05:40:26 +0000 2018","id":998438346987683840,"id_str":"998438346987683840","text":"sometext","display_text_range":[0,0],"source":"u003ca href="someURL" rel="nofollow"u003eTwitter for iPhoneu003c/au003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":1062745482,"id_str":"1062745482","name":"u3074u30fc","screen_name":"maga12171","location":null,"url":null,"description":"u3068u3063u3066u3082u30aau30c8u30cau3067u3059 u706bu661fu4ebauff08uff0buff09 u7652u3057u306fu95a2u30b8u30e3u30cb u6c34u66dcu3069u3046u3067u3057u3087u3046","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":4,"friends_count":23,"listed_count":0,"favourites_count":977,"statuses_count":238,"created_at":"Sat Jan 05 11:09:11 +0000 2013","utc_offset":32400,"time_zone":"Tokyo","geo_enabled":false,"lang":"ja","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"000000","profile_background_image_url":"someURL","profile_background_image_url_https":"https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"0066FF","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"000000","profile_text_color":"000000","profile_use_background_image":false,"profile_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/874952211184222209/UZ8RcGuU_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"someURL","profile_banner_url":"someURL","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[],"media":[{"id":998438345532325888,"id_str":"998438345532325888","indices":[0,23],"media_url":"someURL","media_url_https":"someURL","url":"someURL","display_url":"pic.twitter.com/J1RJGazs8k","expanded_url":"someURL","type":"photo","sizes":{"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"large":{"w":750,"h":1334,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":382,"h":680,"resize":"fit"},"medium":{"w":675,"h":1200,"resize":"fit"}}}]},"extended_entities":{"media":[{"id":998438345532325888,"id_str":"998438345532325888","indices":[0,23],"media_url":"someURL","media_url_https":"someURL","url":"someURL","display_url":"pic.twitter.com/J1RJGazs8k","expanded_url":"someURL","type":"photo","sizes":{"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"large":{"w":750,"h":1334,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":382,"h":680,"resize":"fit"},"medium":{"w":675,"h":1200,"resize":"fit"}}}]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"und","timestamp_ms":"1526881226666"}
```

i have imported them in a mysqldb as text datatype and now i am trying to pull them row by row and clean them up so that i can keep only the data i need.

```
import json
import MySQLdb.cursors

HOST = ""
USER = ""
PASSWD = ""
DB = ""

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=HOST, port =3306, user=USER,passwd=PASSWD,db=DB , cursorclass= MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor)

x = conn.cursor()

query = "SELECT txt_column FROM txt_data limit 1"
x.execute(query)

for row in x:
    print(row)       
    res = json.loads(row[0])
```

when i run it i get : `ValueError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 185 (char 184)` , That is a `"` character found at the `href=`" of the attached json string. A few previous posts in stackoverflow recommend to use .replace() to get rid of the " characters, but this will ruin the json format.

I think the problem is that python expects to find a format like "attribute_name":"data". When it finds "attribute_name":"data "data in quotes" more data" it throughs the error for the unexpected " char

If i am right, is there anyway i can fix this?

Please note i had to modify the json sample attached, substituting all URLs with "someURL", stackoverflow doesn't allow urls. Thus you will not find the error at char 184. In the original data 184 is the first " in href="someURL"

Comment: You did not post the whole stack trace, but it looks like it is raising an exception in `json.loads` because the string you are giving it (`row[0]`) is not a valid JSON string.

Comment: Copy and paste that string into any JSON validator, and it'll show you the problem: you have things like `"source": "u003ca href="someURL" rel="nofollow" u003Twitter for iPhone003c/au003e"`. That may look like a key-value pair to a human, but to a parser, that's the key-value pair `"source": "u003ca href="`, followed by some garbage `someURL`, followed by the string `"ref="`, followed by some more garbage `nofollow`, etc.

Comment: What you've attached isn't a valid JSON. That is your problem. This has nothing to do with what "Python expects", but with what the JSON specification demands.

Comment: you are right. JSON validator output: `Error: Parse error on line 7:
...e": "u003ca href="  //twitter.com/
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'undefined'` Anyway to shape it up?

Comment: Obviously the right fix here is to fix whatever code generated this bogus JSON. But, even if you can do that, you might need to do something with the 5 million broken tweets? If so, there's no easy answer, and no perfect answer; the best you can do is study your data and try to come up with heuristic rules that should usually turn the corrupted garbage into the intended data by adding backslashes or whatever, and then debug the hell out of it.

Comment: Also, if you wrote the code that generates this bogus JSON, the problem is most likely that you're trying to generate JSON strings manually when you should just be calling `json.encode` on some dict, so fixing it will have the nice side effect of making your code a whole lot simpler, faster, and more maintainable.

Comment: i only used tweepy to collect a sample with `twitter_stream.sample()` and saved them in a txt file, then loaded them in my db, so the json comes straight from twitter. Really can't tell what went wrong,

Comment: I just looked at a sample tweepy response https://gist.github.com/hrp/900964 and it shows embedded quotes are properly escaped. Is the example you posted a raw response?

Comment: @ThatUmbrellaGuy yes i am storing the sample in a .txt file and then load it on mysql db using `LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt' INTO TABLE tst character set UTF8mb4` which keeps the data intact. I compared the raw response to my db's content and python's print out, no differences found. Still i am getting ValueError. When i process is it directly from the txt file with the same code exactly everything runs smoothly. When i get it from the db it does not work

Comment: full trace :  `return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 343, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 359, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 204 (char 203)'`

Comment: Answer found here: [Loading and parsing a JSON file with multiple JSON objects in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451431/loading-and-parsing-a-json-file-with-multiple-json-objects-in-python) worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Answer found here:

[Loading and parsing a JSON file with multiple JSON objects in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451431/loading-and-parsing-a-json-file-with-multiple-json-objects-in-python)

worked perfectly

Comment: That is literally just sweeping the problem under the carpet.