# writing to files: switch to new file after X MB file capacity

Tags: python, file, exception, io

I have millions of domains which I will send WHOIS query and record WHOIS response on some .txt file.

I would like to set maximum capacity for a single `.txt` output file. For example, let's say I started recording responses on `out0.txt`. I want to switch to `out1.txt` if `out0.txt` is >= 100mb. Same thing goes for `out1.txt`, if `out1.txt`>=100mb then start writing to `out2.txt`and so on.

I know that I can do `if` checks after each insertion, but I want my code to be fast: i.e. I thought if checks at each domain can slow down my code. (It will asynchronously query millions of domains).

I imagined a try-except block could solve my issue here, like this:

```
folder_name = "out%s.txt"
folder_number = 0


folder_name = folder_name % folder_number
f = open(folder_name, 'w+')

for domain in millions_of_domains:
   try:
      response_json = send_whois_query(domain)
      f.write(response_json)
   except FileGreaterThan100MbException:
      folder_number += 1
      folder_name = folder_name % folder_number
      f = open(folder_name, 'w+')
      f.write(response_json)
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What should happen to data that doesn't fit? Shoud it be written to the next file as a whole? Or should the data be split?

Comment: Note that you *can't just write multiple JSON documents to a file*, not without a delimiter. The JSONLines format uses newlines as the delimiter, and disallows newlines in the JSON documents themselves. Something to think about.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm asynchronously sending queries and fetching JSON responses, which are independent from each other. The JSON file should stay together as a whole, i.e. data can't be split from a single response.

Comment: well, good point. I can wrap them under a big JSON file and put them together as elements of an array, and I can keep that array as a value to some key.

Comment: But then you can no longer split the file. :-)

Comment: I dont understand why I can't split the file. Let's say I put some numbers in that array. out0.txt''s JSON should look like: `{"numbers":[1,2,3]}` and out1.txt's JSON will be like `{"numbers":[4,5,6]}`. replace the numbers with JSON responses from WHOIS call. I can't see what I'm missing here. :)

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood how you were planning to split. Yes, splitting the data by creating separate documents is fine. I have too often seen people try to put everything in one big JSON array (up to and including writing `[` first, then a comma after each document, and `]` at the end).

Comment: That said, it's [trivial to parse a JSON Lines formatted file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451431/loading-and-parsing-a-json-file-with-multiple-json-objects-in-python). If those WHOIS query JSON responses contain newlines, just use `'response_json.replace('\n', '')` to convert those into a JSON Lines compatible format. Newlines in JSON are always extra whitespace that can be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a wrapper object that tracks how much data has been written, and opens a new file if you reached a limit:

```
class MaxSizeFileWriter(object):
    def __init__(self, filenamepattern, maxdata=2**20,  # default 1Mb
                 start=0, mode='w', *args, **kwargs):
        self._pattern = filenamepattern
        self._counter = start

        self._mode = mode
        self._args, self._kwargs = args, kwargs

        self._max = maxdata

        self._openfile = None
        self._written = 0

    def _open(self):
        if self._openfile is not None:
            filename = self._pattern.format(self._counter)
            self._counter += 1
            self._openfile = open(filename, mode=self._mode, *self._args, **self._kwargs)

    def _close(self):
        if self._openfile is not None:
            self._openfile.close()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._openfile is not None:
            self._openfile.close()

    def write(self, data):
        if self._written + len(data) > self._max:
            # current file too full to fit data too, close it
            # This will trigger a new file to be opened.
            self._close()
        self._open()  # noop if already open
        self._openfile.write(data)
        self._written += len(data)
```

The above is a context manager, and can be used just like a regular file. Pass in a filename with a `{}` placeholder for the number to be inserted into:

```
folder_name = "out{}.txt"

with MaxSizeFileWriter(folder_name, maxdata=100 * 2**10) as f:
    for domain in millions_of_domains:
        response_json = send_whois_query(domain)
        f.write(response_json)
```