# Merge multiple JSON objects into a single JSON object

Tags: python, json

I have a log file containing one JSON record per line.

```
{"eventVersion":"1.08","userIdentity":{"type":"AssumedRole","principalId":"AA:i-096379450e69ed082","arn":"arn:aws:sts::34502sdsdsd:assumed-role/RDSAccessRole/i-096379450e69ed082","accountId":"34502sdsdsd","accessKeyId":"ASIAVAVKXAXXXXXXXC","sessionContext":{"sessionIssuer":{"type":"Role","principalId":"AROAVAVKXAKDDDDD","arn":"arn:aws:iam::3450291sdsdsd:role/RDSAccessRole","accountId":"345029asasas","userName":"RDSAccessRole"},"webIdFederationData":{},"attributes":{"mfaAuthenticated":"false","creationDate":"2021-04-27T04:38:52Z"},"ec2RoleDelivery":"2.0"}},"eventTime":"2021-04-27T07:24:20Z","eventSource":"ssm.amazonaws.com","eventName":"ListInstanceAssociations","awsRegion":"us-east-1","sourceIPAddress":"188.208.227.188","userAgent":"aws-sdk-go/1.25.41 (go1.13.15; linux; amd64) amazon-ssm-agent/","requestParameters":{"instanceId":"i-096379450e69ed082","maxResults":20},"responseElements":null,"requestID":"a5c63b9d-aaed-4a3c-9b7d-a4f7c6b774ab","eventID":"70de51df-c6df-4a57-8c1e-0ffdeb5ac29d","readOnly":true,"resources":[{"accountId":"34502914asasas","ARN":"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:3450291asasas:instance/i-096379450e69ed082"}],"eventType":"AwsApiCall","managementEvent":true,"eventCategory":"Management","recipientAccountId":"345029149342"}
{"eventVersion":"1.08","userIdentity":{"type":"AssumedRole","principalId":"AROAVAVKXAKPKZ25XXXX:AmazonMWAA-airflow","arn":"arn:aws:sts::3450291asasas:assumed-role/dev-1xdcfd/AmazonMWAA-airflow","accountId":"34502asasas","accessKeyId":"ASIAVAVKXAXXXXXXX","sessionContext":{"sessionIssuer":{"type":"Role","principalId":"AROAVAVKXAKPKZXXXXX","arn":"arn:aws:iam::345029asasas:role/service-role/AmazonMWAA-dlp-dev-1xdcfd","accountId":"3450291asasas","userName":"dlp-dev-1xdcfd"},"webIdFederationData":{},"attributes":{"mfaAuthenticated":"false","creationDate":"2021-04-27T07:04:08Z"}},"invokedBy":"airflow.amazonaws.com"},"eventTime":"2021-04-27T07:23:46Z","eventSource":"logs.amazonaws.com","eventName":"CreateLogStream","awsRegion":"us-east-1","sourceIPAddress":"airflow.amazonaws.com","userAgent":"airflow.amazonaws.com","errorCode":"ResourceAlreadyExistsException","errorMessage":"The specified log stream already exists","requestParameters":{"logStreamName":"scheduler.py.log","logGroupName":"dlp-dev-DAGProcessing"},"responseElements":null,"requestID":"40b48ef9-fc4b-4d1a-8fd1-4f2584aff1e9","eventID":"ef608d43-4765-4a3a-9c92-14ef35104697","readOnly":false,"eventType":"AwsApiCall","apiVersion":"20140328","managementEvent":true,"eventCategory":"Management","recipientAccountId":"3450291asasas"}
```

My goal is to merge this into a single json object which should look like:

```
{"Records":[{"eventVersion":"1.08","userIdentity":{"type":"AssumedRole","principalId":.....
```

I have been trying out merging them through Python dict merge but not able to get it to work.
Can anyone provide some pointers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading and parsing a JSON file with multiple JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451431/loading-and-parsing-a-json-file-with-multiple-json-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your records are stored separated by newlines in a text file I would recommend the following approach by opening the file, parsing the records, and adding them to a dict which you can later dump with the native json library.

```
import json
data = {'records': []}

with open("data.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        data['records'].append(json.loads(line))
        
print(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: how can I get rid of the multiple '\' been added in the json.

Comment: okay, I got it. changed to json.loads(line)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
{"eventVersion":"1.08","userIdentity":{"type":"AssumedRole","principalId":"AA:i-096379450e69ed082","arn":"arn:aws:sts::34502sdsdsd:assumed-role/RDSAccessRole/i-096379450e69ed082","accountId":"34502sdsdsd","accessKeyId":"ASIAVAVKXAXXXXXXXC","sessionContext":{"sessionIssuer":{"type":"Role","principalId":"AROAVAVKXAKDDDDD","arn":"arn:aws:iam::3450291sdsdsd:role/RDSAccessRole","accountId":"345029asasas","userName":"RDSAccessRole"},"webIdFederationData":{},"attributes":{"mfaAuthenticated":"false","creationDate":"2021-04-27T04:38:52Z"},"ec2RoleDelivery":"2.0"}},"eventTime":"2021-04-27T07:24:20Z","eventSource":"ssm.amazonaws.com","eventName":"ListInstanceAssociations","awsRegion":"us-east-1","sourceIPAddress":"188.208.227.188","userAgent":"aws-sdk-go/1.25.41 (go1.13.15; linux; amd64) amazon-ssm-agent/","requestParameters":{"instanceId":"i-096379450e69ed082","maxResults":20},"responseElements":null,"requestID":"a5c63b9d-aaed-4a3c-9b7d-a4f7c6b774ab","eventID":"70de51df-c6df-4a57-8c1e-0ffdeb5ac29d","readOnly":true,"resources":[{"accountId":"34502914asasas","ARN":"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:3450291asasas:instance/i-096379450e69ed082"}],"eventType":"AwsApiCall","managementEvent":true,"eventCategory":"Management","recipientAccountId":"345029149342"}
{"eventVersion":"1.08","userIdentity":{"type":"AssumedRole","principalId":"AROAVAVKXAKPKZ25XXXX:AmazonMWAA-airflow","arn":"arn:aws:sts::3450291asasas:assumed-role/dev-1xdcfd/AmazonMWAA-airflow","accountId":"34502asasas","accessKeyId":"ASIAVAVKXAXXXXXXX","sessionContext":{"sessionIssuer":{"type":"Role","principalId":"AROAVAVKXAKPKZXXXXX","arn":"arn:aws:iam::345029asasas:role/service-role/AmazonMWAA-dlp-dev-1xdcfd","accountId":"3450291asasas","userName":"dlp-dev-1xdcfd"},"webIdFederationData":{},"attributes":{"mfaAuthenticated":"false","creationDate":"2021-04-27T07:04:08Z"}},"invokedBy":"airflow.amazonaws.com"},"eventTime":"2021-04-27T07:23:46Z","eventSource":"logs.amazonaws.com","eventName":"CreateLogStream","awsRegion":"us-east-1","sourceIPAddress":"airflow.amazonaws.com","userAgent":"airflow.amazonaws.com","errorCode":"ResourceAlreadyExistsException","errorMessage":"The specified log stream already exists","requestParameters":{"logStreamName":"scheduler.py.log","logGroupName":"dlp-dev-DAGProcessing"},"responseElements":null,"requestID":"40b48ef9-fc4b-4d1a-8fd1-4f2584aff1e9","eventID":"ef608d43-4765-4a3a-9c92-14ef35104697","readOnly":false,"eventType":"AwsApiCall","apiVersion":"20140328","managementEvent":true,"eventCategory":"Management","recipientAccountId":"3450291asasas"}
```

then

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    jsons = [i.strip() for i in f.readlines()]
with open('total.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write('{"Records":[')
    f.write(','.join(jsons))
    f.write(']}')
```

will produce `total.json` with desired shape and being legal JSON if every line inside `file.txt` is legal JSON.