# Python: Json.Load Extra Data

Tags: python, json, database, load

I'm trying to load in json objects from a file we'll call `database.db`. The objects in this database are

```
{"name":"apple"}
{"name":"banana"}
{"name":"cranberry"}
```

I was able to load in data perfectly when the format of the document was...

```
{
fruits = [

    {"name":"apple"}
    {"name":"banana"}
    {"name":"cranberry"}
]
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't simply add in the `fruits =` portion to the new `database.db` and was wondering if there was a work around here. The error i'm getting is `Extra data: line 2 column 1`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading and parsing a JSON file with multiple JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451431/loading-and-parsing-a-json-file-with-multiple-json-objects)

Comment: @ValentinKuhn I just used the same methodology messing around and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: None of these are valid JSON...