# Read JSON Lines file as String in Python

Tags: python, json, jsonlines

I have a **JSON Lines** file that I would like to read as a string in Python. The file contains multiple JSON objects in this format:

```
{"Data1": "Value1"}
{"Data2": "Value2"}
{"Data3": "Value3"}
```

I tried the following code in Python but it returned an error. I was able to load the file as a list of dictionaries using `lines = []` but apprently it doesn't work for a string. How can I read the whole file as a string?

```
import json

lines = ''

with open('file.json', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        lines.append(json.loads(line))
```

Comment: Please share the contents of `links.jl` (or at least a relevant part of it) in your question.

Comment: you can try `f.read()`

Comment: Can you explain, in your own words, what you think `json.loads()` does? Why are you trying to load a single line of JSON (which should fail as a single line wouldn't necessarily be syntactically-valid JSON) and subsequently append the resulting object to a string? Why not just read the entire file in with `readlines()` then use `json.loads()` on the resulting string to serialize it into Python data structures? It's really not clear to me where you got the idea that this methodology should work - can you link to the example or documentation on which you're basing your attempt here?

Comment: and then load a string once, something like: `json_str=‘[‘ + f.read().replace(‘\n’, ‘,\n’) + ‘]’; json.loads(json_str)`

Comment: @esqew well he mentioned it’s in jsonl format, where each line is basically a valid map type. I mean it’s not valid jaon as a whole, since there’s no open close braces [] in the file presumably.

Comment: @esqew Since the file is in JSONL format, it needs to be parsed line by line as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451431/loading-and-parsing-a-json-file-with-multiple-json-objects. I wanted to achieve the same but loading the file as a string as opposed to a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to read a **JSON Lines** document as a string would be to use the `read()` function as follow:

```
with open("file.json", "r") as file:
    data_str = file.read()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `f.read()` if you aren't worried about the memory usage in case of large files or else your implementation seems fine, except the part which you are trying to use `append()` with string. This can be achieved through simple modification

```py
lines = ""
with open("links.jl", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        lines += line
```

Comment: This worked! Can you explain what `lines += line` is doing?

Comment: It will add both operands if they're integers or concatenate them if they're strings and assign the result to the left side operand, which can also be written as `lines = lines + line`

Answer (score -1):

you can use following template to load your JSON string into the DataFram

```python
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json (r'C:\Users\Ron\Desktop\data.json')
print (df)
```

Comment: it should be the following for json lines file:

df = pd.read_json('C:\Users\Ron\Desktop\data.json', lines=True)