# Extract key , value from dictionary and store it in new list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have data in the following format.

```
{"id": 0, "key1": value, "key2": "value", "imp_key": {"sub_key1": 5, "sub_key2": 10, "sub_key3": 15}}
{"id": 1, "key1": value, "key2": "value", "imp_key": {"sub_key1": 5, "sub_key2": 10, "sub_key3": 15}}
{"id": 2, "key1": value, "key2": "value", "imp_key": {"sub_key1": 5, "sub_key2": 10, "sub_key3": 15}}
```

I want to extract the key 'id' and 'imp_key' features from this data and store them in a new list. The dataset is quiet big, but similar format. The subkey, value pair content numeric data.

desired output:

```
[{"id": 0, "imp_key": {"sub_key1": 5, "sub_key2": 10, "sub_key3": 15}},
     {"id": 1, "imp_key": {"sub_key1": 5, "sub_key2": 10, "sub_key3": 15}},
     {"id": 2, "imp_key": {"sub_key1": 5, "sub_key2": 10, "sub_key3": 15}}
    ]
```

Can anyone help with extracting the data from list?
Thank you.

Comment: And `null` is invalid python. `None`, perhaps?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3001761

Comment: One part of your question is answered here, I guess: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451431/loading-and-parsing-a-json-file-with-multiple-json-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your input data is actually in the format:

```
l = [{"id": 0, "key1": "value", "key2": "value", "imp_key": {"sub_key1": None, "sub_key2": None, "sub_key3": None}},
{"id": 1, "key1": "value", "key2": "value", "imp_key": {"sub_key1": None, "sub_key2": None, "sub_key3": None}},
{"id": 2, "key1": "value", "key2": "value", "imp_key": {"sub_key1": None, "sub_key2": None, "sub_key3": None}}]
```

You could do something like this:

```
newl = []
for x in l:
    newx = x.copy()
    newx.pop("key1")
    newx.pop("key2")
    newl.append(newx)
print(newl)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 0, 'imp_key': {'sub_key1': None, 'sub_key2': None, 'sub_key3': None}}, {'id': 1, 'imp_key': {'sub_key1': None, 'sub_key2': None, 'sub_key3': None}}, {'id': 2, 'imp_key': {'sub_key1': None, 'sub_key2': None, 'sub_key3': None}}]
```