# How to parse the bytes of string to dict in python

Tags: python

I have received from message from client as bellow

```
b'{"time": 1234.23432, "message": "Printer1"}{"time": 63743.4332, "message": "Printer2"}{"time": 82374.43253, "message": "Printer3"}'
```

I would like parse this into a list of dict

Example:

```
[{"time": 1234.23432, "message": "Printer1"}, {"time": 63743.4332, "message": "Printer2"}, {"time": 82374.43253, "message": "Printer3"}]
```

I tried by using

```
parsedMessage = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

But it throughs an error.

can anyone have any idea that how can I parse it?

Comment: What error is thrown? Did you try using "ascii" instead of "utf-8"? Please show a [mre].

Comment: Well, it's invalid JSON. I wouldn't know of another format that allows direct concatenation of dicts without delimiter. Good luck parsing that. Try getting the data from the client in a _valid_ format.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451431/loading-and-parsing-a-json-file-with-multiple-json-objects

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```py
s=b'{"time": 1234.23432, "message": "Printer1"}{"time": 63743.4332, "message": "Printer2"}{"time": 82374.43253, "message": "Printer3"}'
out = [json.loads('{'+l+'}') for l in s.decode("utf-8")[1:-1].split('}{')]
```

Comment: This’ll break if any string inside the JSON objects should contain “}{“.

Comment: I know, but I would say that is pretty unlikely, especially with how the string seems to be formatted.